# Game character won't stop moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character that moves up, down, left, right across the plane. What I can't get her to do is stop moving. She's basically an endless runner right now, when I press the d-pad, she begins walking and never stops again. I believe my issue is in the `transform.position` line written in the `Update` function, but not sure what to add to it to get her to stop.

```
public float speed = 16;

int RunningHash;
int WalkingHash;

PlayerInput input;

Vector2 currentMovement;
bool movementPressed;
bool runPressed;

void OnEnable() 
{ 
    input.CharacterControls.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    input.CharacterControls.Disable();  
}

void Awake()
{
    input = new PlayerInput();

    input.CharacterControls.Movement.performed += ctx =>
    {
        currentMovement = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        movementPressed = currentMovement.x != 0 || currentMovement.y != 0;
    };
    input.CharacterControls.Running.performed += ctx => runPressed = ctx.ReadValueAsButton();
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    RunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("Running");
    WalkingHash = Animator.StringToHash("Walking");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    handleMovement();
    handleRotation();
    
    transform.position += new Vector3(currentMovement.x, 0, currentMovement.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

void handleRotation()
{
    Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;

    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(currentMovement.x, 0, currentMovement.y);

    Vector3 positionToLookAt = currentPosition + newPosition;

    transform.LookAt(positionToLookAt);
}

void handleMovement()
{
    bool Running = animator.GetBool(RunningHash);
    bool Walking = animator.GetBool(WalkingHash);

    if (movementPressed && !Walking)
    {
        animator.SetBool(WalkingHash, true);

    }
    
    if (!movementPressed && Walking)
    {
        animator.SetBool(WalkingHash, false);
    }

    if ((movementPressed && runPressed) && !Running)
    {
        animator.SetBool(RunningHash, true);

    }
    
    if ((!movementPressed || !runPressed) && Running)
    {
        animator.SetBool(RunningHash, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Make the character move always or only when the controls are pressed? If that's the case, do not use Update function, but apply your movement only when the buttons/controls are pressed.

Comment: I removed the line in the update function and checked apply root motion instead. but she still walks endlessly, Yes I'd like to get the character to move only when pressing the joystick, but can't figure out where the change should be made.

Answer (score 0):

You set currentMovement in response to `input.CharacterControls.Movement.performed` but as far as I can see you never reset it in response to releasing the input.

Answer (score 0):

`transform.position += new Vector3(currentMovement.x, 0, currentMovement.y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;` will just keep running endlessly because it is in the update method.
If you don't want this, then move it out of the update method or add a check to see if the character should move.

Comment: I realized that removing this line and then checking apply root motion was what the original tutorial intended for me to do. But now she still walks endlessly. I think the issue is in the If statements, I just can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: Hey Jim perhaps either update your question with the new code you wrote, or make a new question. That way me and others might be able to help you further :)